# Mysql LEFT JOIN and SUM and show 0 instead of NULL

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I have first table named "orders" and 2nd table named "details"

```
orders :
order_id
1
2
3

details :
id | order_id | qty
1  |  1       | 2
2  |  1       | 3
```

How do I show as follows ?

```
order_id | total
1        | 5
2        | 0
3        | 0
```

I tried this query but didn't work :

```
SELECT *, SUM(qty) AS total
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN details d
  ON o.order_id = d.order_id
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.order_id, IFNULL(SUM(d.qty),0) AS total
FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN details d ON o.order_id = d.order_id
 GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: @MarcusAdams `GROUP BY 1` groups by the first column, not hugely readable, but it works.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, not according to his original post, there are 0s in the desired results example.

Comment: @Arth, ah, I'll fix his question then.

Answer (score 8):

This will do what you are asking. It will replace the `null` values with `0` if there is an order with no detail record.

```
SELECT o.order_id, 
       COALESCE(sum(d.qty), 0)
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN details d ON o.order_id = d.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id;
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle Example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1947d/11)

Comment: +1 . . . Use of ANSI standard `coalesce()`.  SQL Fiddle example.  Use of table aliases.  My only suggestion:  the table aliases should be table abbreviations, so I prefer `o` and `d` rather than `a` and `b`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I have updated the example and answer per your suggestion.